# What is the best way to prove a processor is overheating / running too hot?

Tags: laptop, cpu, temperature

recently I noticed that my sister's laptop was getting very very hot when it sat on my lap, she had also complained that it just turned off on her without warning... so I decided to run Coretemp and Everest to test processor temperature.(It is an AMD Athlon X2... not sure what it runs at.) It seemed to idle around 75-80 Celsius and under 100% load it peaked at 115 ! I realize that laptops run a lot hotter than desktop but I think that is ridiculously hot...am I right?

Anyway... Her laptop is still under warranty and I was wondering what is the best way to prove to future shop that it is running that hot. Should I give them a printout of a stress test or something like that? Or should I just bring it in to them and tell them what I think is wrong and let them test it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Just bring it in to them and tell them what I think is wrong and let them test it.

That's what they'll have to do anyway.

But before you give it up for repair.
**Be sure to remove any private files you don't want anyone to see on the internet, emails, passwords saved in web browsers.**

If it was me I'd backup everything and do a complete system wipe and do a reinstallation of windows before handing my computer over to some unknown technician.

Comment: wholly agree - don't do the work for them! let them make their own findings and use this as a backup argument if they deny the issue